# Play Framework Form validation messages with Twitter Bootstrap fields

Tags: scala, twitter-bootstrap, playframework

I'm trying to change the text of the validation messages showing in my forms created with Play framework

[image]

The text like 'Required', 'Numeric', 'Date(yyyy...)' is shown automatically depending on the type of the property binded to the form field.

```
@implicitFieldConstructor = @{
    FieldConstructor(twitterBootstrapInput.f)
}

<fieldset>
  @inputText(productForm("id"), '_label -> "Product id")
  @inputText(productForm("info.name"), '_label -> "Name", 'placeholder -> "Product Name")
  @inputText(productForm("info.code"), '_label -> "Code")
  @inputText(productForm("info.weight"), '_label -> "Weight")
 @inputDate(productForm("info.dateAdded"), '_label -> "Date Added")
</fieldset>
```

This is all pretty nice but I wonder how can I change it. Is it possible by using some attribute on `@inputText` element, eg. smth like `'_helpinline -> "Please enter the name"` (I did look for smth like this but couldn't find anything), maybe there are other ways people use?

Those messages are shown within Twitter bootstrap `help-inline` styled element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While error message can be easily changed by passing `message` param to constraint annotation (like `@Required(message = "abc")`), this is not true for these infos. Actually, that is where they are defined: in an annotation with which constratin annotation is annotated itself *(so meta)*. Just [see source](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-java/src/main/java/play/data/validation/Constraints.java#L75) if I'm explaining too difficult. Note the `@play.data.Form.Display(name="constraint.required")` line.

So, what we can do with this?

**Option 1: if you want to change this for *ALL* @Required fields.** As you see, this annotation defines not the message itself, but its *localization key*. So you can override this in your localization, just by adding the following line in your `conf/messages.en`:

```
constraint.required=This is so very required!
```

And then to all other language files.

**Option 2: if you want each input have different message given as a parameter**. Then you don't need at all to go into this validation mechanism, you can just modify your *field constructor*. [Here is the source](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/helper/twitterBootstrap/twitterBootstrapFieldConstructor.scala.html) of built-in twitter bootstrap field contructor. Make your own by copying it (if you didn't yet), and put everything you want into `<span class="help-inline">`. For example, to handle `'_helpinline -> "Please enter the name"`, the 14'th line may be the following:

```
<span class="help-inline">
    @elements.args.get('_helpinline).getOrElse( elements.errors(elements.lang).mkString(", ") )
</span>
```

You see, I put the initial value into `getOrElse`, so that if you don't provide any `'_helpinline` the default info is used.

**Option 3: if you want each input have different message, customized via annotation just like `@Required(message = "abc")`.** Then you might want to make your own custom @Require annotation, by copypasting it from [the source](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-java/src/main/java/play/data/validation/Constraints.java#L75) and making some modification. This is the most tricky option, I think Option 2 is better, but still, it is useful to know how to make own validator annotation since it is not as difficult as it seems.

Hope some of these variants will help. I bet on the 2nd, actually :)

Comment: Do you know by any chance where you can find a list of default localization message keys (like constraint.required)?

Comment: They are also in source. In this case it is in https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/resources/messages